# Setting up xdebug within Aptana on Docksal site

Tags: aptana3

Bear with me - I'm learning as I go, and this is all new to me. I've set up Docksal on Mac OSX, and added an existing site. I've also got Xdebug installed. In order to use it, it appears I need an IDE. I've installed Aptana (no budget for pay services).

I'm trying to figure out how to set up the debugging within Aptana. I see old instructions from 2013 and older. They get me into the general area, of adding a PHP interpreter. But I'm stumped from here.

I don't know what to put in the Name and executable path (if I'm even in the right place for this) when I search for PHP.exe, nothing comes up. When I search for php.ini, I just find files sitting in unrelated Acquia Dev Desktop projects.

Answer (score 0):

I may have accidentally managed to answer my own question.

In terminal, I first typed **`php --ini`** , but this gave me (none). 
Next I tried **`sudo find / -type f -name php.ini`**
After entering the system password, I get three results:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
/usr/local/php5-7.1.10-20171002-090111/lib/php.ini
```

Next, for the .exe file path, I typed **`which php`**
This gave me `/usr/bin/php`

So, within Aptana Studio 3, I went to Preferences. In the sidebar file tree I navigated to Aptana Studio > Editors > PHP > PHP Interpreters. Click the "Add" button. (This is where I got to, before realizing I couldn't find those files.

from the results above, I added my info:

In executable path, I placed: /usr/bin/php

In PHP.ini files, I placed: /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini

Press save, and that part "seems" to be solved. Here's hoping it works. I see errors in the bottom pane of Aptana when viewing a php file - so that's promising.